# JSON.stringify() - object's custom serializer

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

Let's say I have an object:

```
const a = {
  foo: 123,
  bar: 'example'
}
```

This object is a part of many other objects i.e.

```
const b = {
  a: a,
  anotherField: "example"
}
```

Actually, I'm using TypeScript and all these objects are of the same class which I believe isn't important.

After serializing the `b` object to JSON I need to get this string (i.e. I just get the `foo` field from `a`):

`{ a: 123, anotherField: "example" }`

What is the easiest and most elegant way to tell `JSON.stringify()` how to convert the `a` object to a string?

Probably something similar to what `Python` allows.

Comment: Definitely, you have another problem because the `JSON.stringify` will convert to string that js object.

Comment: Actually, none. JSON.stringify just converts the object to a JSON-compliant string, you can transform the object **before** serializing it. It's not really language-related, it's just a bad design, in this case, in my opinion.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could define `toJSON` in `a`.

> If an object being stringified has a property named toJSON whose value is a function, then the toJSON() method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the toJSON() method when called will be serialized.

(source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior))

For example:

```js
class A {
  constructor(foo, bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  toJSON() {
    return this.foo;
  }
}

const a = new A(123, "some name");
const b = {
  a: a,
  anotherField: "example"
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(b)); // "{"a":123,"anotherField":"example"}"
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use the replacer while stringifying:

```
 const result = JSON.stringify(b, (k, v) => v && v.stringify() || v);
```

That way you can easily add a custom stringification to `a`:

```
 const a = {
   foo: 123,
   bar: 'example',
   stringify() { return this.foo; }
 }
```