# ES6 Map autoconverted to {}?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

In my React Native + TypeScript app, I've defined a bunch of types as follows:

```
export type Streak = {
    ...
    marked: Map<number, string>
};

export type Habit = {
  ... 
  ...
  streak: Streak,
  ...
}
```

When I save `Habit` to AsyncStorage and read it back, I seem to be losing the `Map` type of the `marked` field, since I get `marked` back as an object `{}` type, and I cannot invoke functions like `keys()` or `has()` etc on `marked`.

```
await AsyncStorage.setItem(habit.key, JSON.stringify(habit));
....
....
let res = await AsyncStorage.getItem(habit.key);
let habit: Habit = JSON.parse(res); // I thought specifying the type Habit here would have given me `marked` back as a Map

if (habit.streak.marked.has(<someKey>)) { ... }
```

`TypeError:  ... marked.has is not a function ...`

What should I be doing to preserve the `Map` type?

Comment: You can't preserve it. It's the way JSON deserialization is implemented in JavaScript. You'll have to create the map again manually. You could of course create a [custom serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52895457/json-stringify-objects-custom-serializer) but I'd say that's overkill for this simple problem.

Comment: Thank you! Bummer, but that's good to know.